# Use the (cin) user input to paste it in std::system and run a command with the input in another terminal

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gnome-terminal

Use the (cin) user input to paste it in std::system and run a command with the input in another terminal

```
int main() {
    string ip;
    cout << "IP to scan: ";
    cin >> ip;

    std::system(" nmap .... ")

    return 0;
}
```

so basicly I want the string ip to be used in an gnome ternimal so I can do for example and nmap scan of the ip that the user typed

Comment: its unclear what is the question. What happens when you just do what you want to do? Doesnt it work?

Comment: _run a command with the input in another terminal_ Then you have to call `gterm` in `system()`. You can provide the command `nmap` as command line argument e.g. `system("gterm -e \"nmap .... \"");` or `system("gterm -x nmap .... ")`. Found this in doc.: [gnome-terminal - Options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html#options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be easily done using string formatting:

```
int main() // ; << Note this is wrong!
{
    string ip;
    cout << "IP to scan: ";
    cin >> ip;

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "nmap " << ip;

    std::system(os.str().c_str());

    // return 0; isn't necessary    
}
```

---

To run that command in a different terminal window, you have to call the terminal program with `system()`, as scheff mentioned in their comment

```
os << "gterm -e \"nmap " << ip "\"";
std::system(os.str().c_str());
```

Comment: stu.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
stu.cpp:11:24: error: aggregate ‘std::ostringstream os’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     std::ostringstream os;
                        ^~

Comment: @TheUnknownGuy There are some includes missing: `#include <iostream>` `#include <sstream>` `#include <string>`.

Comment: @TheUnknownGuy Use `#include <sstream>`. Also refer to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) for further questions please.

Comment: @TheUnknownGuy ...and you probably must insert `using namespace std;` before `main()`.

Comment: @TheUnknownGuy I don't see what makes the difference regarding multiple inputs. Just use a loop or such.